# Java trait workaround

Tags: java, traits, mixins

I was playing around with the new default functions in interfaces, and needed a way to have trait-like behaviour for a set of classes.

What I came up with is this:

```
public interface Resource {

    Map<Resource, AnalysisTag<?>> tags = new WeakHashMap<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    default AnalysisTag<?> getTag() {
        return tags.get(this);
    }

    default Resource tag(AnalysisTag<?> tag) {
        tags.put(this, tag);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Here, the Resource interface defines behaviour for an implementing class to be able to store tags associated with a specific object. When the object loses all references in other parts of the code, the WeakHashMap will clean it up automatically.

WeakHashMaps do not block GC of its keys.

My question is, is this safe? Anything I should beware of?

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is this safe?

AFAIK ... yes ... in the sense that it shouldn't lead to memory leaks.

> Anything I should beware of?

One problem is that `WeakHashMap` uses `WeakReference` and `WeakReference` are relatively expensive for the garbage collector to deal with.  The reference queues are processed after the GC proper has run and the default in a lot of JVMs is to have only one thread to process them.  This can slow the reclamation of (in this case) `WeakHashMap` entries which can have knock-on effects on performance.

It took me a bit of time to figure out how this is supposed to work.  (I forgot that `tags` is implicitly `static final` because it is declared in an interface.  Duh!)  I think it will probably work as a "mixin" to add a "has a Tag" trait to a class.  However, it is an expensive way of doing it.  Adding a `private Tag<?> tag` field + getter and setter in the classes that implement `Resource` would be a lot more efficient.

The code would be easier to understand (for old-school Java programmers who pay attention to identifier naming cues) if `tags` was renamed to `TAGS`.

Comment: How much of a penalty would this be on a long-running program?

Comment: Well ... it depends on how frequently `Resource` instances are created and garbage collected, and how often the tag operations are called.  And stuff like that.

Comment: They would be created quite frequently, they are basically the DTOs of my application. They would also be unreferenced quickly, as they dont need to stay in memory for long.

Comment: Well then, you need to consider the GC performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... the two problems with your solution I see:

1. The access to `tags` is not secure, any other class can manipulate that. More on that below.
2. The retrieval is not optimal in terms of speed. However, this is widely accepted in the Java community, as abominations like ThreadLocal also exist. So let's accept that.

So what you need to do is protect the map from malicious access.
I have built three examples with increasing security considerations.

**Examples package structure:**

```
stackoverflow.trait0r/
    AnalysisTag.java
    Trait0r.java
    /bad/
        BadResource.java
    /better/
        BetterResource.java
        BetterResourceContainer.java
    /best/
        BestResource.java
        BestResourceContainer.java
        SamePackageIllegalAccessTest.java
```

**Example 1: Yours, just a tick improved**

```
package stackoverflow.trait0r.bad;

import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import stackoverflow.trait0r.AnalysisTag;

public interface BadResource {
    /* best to always use full type (WeakHashMap instead of Map) when in control of code.
     * so downcast is always possible and upcast never necessary.
     * Plus access to the references object is usually faster
     */
    WeakHashMap<BadResource, AnalysisTag<?>> tags = new WeakHashMap<>();
    default AnalysisTag<?> getTag() {
        return tags.get(this);
    }
    default BadResource tag(final AnalysisTag<?> tag) {
        tags.put(this, tag);
        return this;
    }
}
```

**Example 2: A bit better, making use of package protected**

```
package stackoverflow.trait0r.better;

import stackoverflow.trait0r.AnalysisTag;

public interface BetterResource {
    default AnalysisTag<?> getTag() {
        return BetterResourceConainer.tags.get(this);
    }
    default BetterResource tag(final AnalysisTag<?> tag) {
        BetterResourceConainer.tags.put(this, tag);
        return this;
    }
}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.trait0r.better;

import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import stackoverflow.trait0r.AnalysisTag;

class BetterResourceConainer {
    static /* package */ WeakHashMap<BetterResource, AnalysisTag<?>> tags = new WeakHashMap<>();
}
```

**Example 3: best protection: package protected AND Thread access check**

```
package stackoverflow.trait0r.best;

import stackoverflow.trait0r.AnalysisTag;

public interface BestResource {
    default AnalysisTag<?> getTag() {
        return BestResourceConainer.getTag(this);
    }
    default BestResource tag(final AnalysisTag<?> tag) {
        BestResourceConainer.setTag(this, tag);
        return this;
    }
}
```

and

```
package stackoverflow.trait0r.best;

import java.util.WeakHashMap;

import stackoverflow.trait0r.AnalysisTag;

class BestResourceConainer {
    static private WeakHashMap<BestResource, AnalysisTag<?>> tags = new WeakHashMap<>();
    static private void ensureAccess() {
        final int CALLER_INDEX = 3;
        final StackTraceElement[] st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        if (st.length < CALLER_INDEX + 1) throw new IllegalAccessError("Cannot access BestResourceConainer via external caller!");

        final StackTraceElement ste = st[CALLER_INDEX];
        final boolean grantAccess = BestResource.class.getName().equals(ste.getClassName());
        if (!grantAccess) throw new IllegalAccessError("Cannot access BestResourceConainer via external caller!");
    }
    static /* package */ void setTag(final BestResource pRes, final AnalysisTag<?> pTag) {
        ensureAccess();
        tags.put(pRes, pTag);
    }
    static AnalysisTag<?> getTag(final BestResource pRes) {
        ensureAccess();
        return tags.get(pRes);
    }
}
```

and an attempt at a dirty little hack:

```
package stackoverflow.trait0r.best;

import stackoverflow.trait0r.AnalysisTag;

public class SamePackageIllegalAccessTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        try {
            BestResourceConainer.setTag(new BestResource() {/**/}, new AnalysisTag<>("[ malicious hack ]"));
            System.out.println("Write successful!");
        } catch (final Error e) {
            System.out.println("Write access failed as expected");
        }

        try {
            final AnalysisTag<?> tag = BestResourceConainer.getTag(new BestResource() {/**/});
            System.out.println("TAG: " + tag);
//                      ThreadLocal<String> x;
        } catch (final Error e) {
            System.out.println("Read access failed as expected");
        }
    }

}
```

So as you see, if you really want a somewhat secure management of the `tags` map, there are some techniques that allow that.

Note however, that you might have to adjust the `CALLER_INDEX`, and that this still can be spoofed if the `BestResource` class is replaced from the very beginning on with another implementation of the same classname.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this issue, and I think that using a package private wrapper class for the tags map should be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

Generally this is fine, though as soon as you start to use field members I would consider using an abstract class and making your map private/final.

Checkout the following for more info...

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184945/why-is-an-interface-in-java-not-allowed-to-have-state

https://www.baeldung.com/java-weakhashmap

Comment: The problem with using abstract classes is that you cannot have multiple inheritance, and records cannot extend classes.

Comment: This is true but normally implies an issue with the design. Rather than having multiple classes inherit your interface you should have a single implementation which you supply to multiple classes. 

So you have another base class (abstract class) and this accepts your interface via a constructor(or a method parameter where needed). 

This will then make unit testing easier as you only test that interface in isolation and then your other classes are no longer concerned about the implemention during testing as you’ll supply a mock. It’s to keep your classes simple